# Add span with class tag after the li tag in yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I am new in yii framework.
I need an output like this html code

```
<ul class="yw0">
    <li><span class="highlighter"></span><a href="#">Sign in</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Register</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The code would be similar something but what would be the exact code to create an extra **`<span class="highlighter"></span>`** after the li tag and before the a tag**

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
    'id'=>'menu',
        'items'=>array(                
            array('label'=>'Signin', 'url'=>array('/site/signin')),
            array('label'=>'Register', 'url'=>array('/site/register'))
        ),            
    )); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At Last I got the answer. 
 For Global Item

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
    'id'=>'menu',
    'itemTemplate' => '<span class="highlighter"></span>{menu}',
    'items'=>array(                
        array('label'=>'Signin', 'url'=>array('/site/signin')),
        array('label'=>'Register', 'url'=>array('/site/register'))
    ),            
)); ?>
```

And For Single Item

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
    'id'=>'menu',
    'items'=>array(                
        array('label'=>'Signin', 'url'=>array('/site/signin'), 'template' => '<span class="highlighter"></span>{menu}'),
        array('label'=>'Register', 'url'=>array('/site/register'))
    ),            
)); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Extend `CMenu` with your own class and ovverride `renderMenuItem`, for example

```
protected function renderMenuItem($item)
{
    $html = parent::renderMenuItem($item)
    if(isset($item['highlighter']))
    {
         $html = "<span class='highlighter'></span>$html"
    }
    return $html;
}
```

And use it like that:

```
<?php $this->widget('alias.to.your.Class',array(
    'id'=>'menu',
        'items'=>array(                
            array('label'=>'Signin', 'highlighter' => true, 'url'=>array('/site/signin')),
            array('label'=>'Register', 'url'=>array('/site/register'))
        ),            
    )); ?>
```